# Presenting view controller from detached view controller is discouraged

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to implement Firework ios sdk to my project. need to implement "videoFeedController" in a table view cell, i tried the below code but xcode is giving this error "Presenting view controller  from detached view controller is discouraged"  and when i dismiss a video the videoFeedController disappears from the cell. But i want to keep it. How to solve problem?

```
        self.feedVC?.addChild(self.videoFeedViewController)
        cell.contentView.addSubview(videoFeedViewController.view)
        
        self.videoFeedViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   
        cell.contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: videoFeedViewController.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        cell.contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: videoFeedViewController.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        cell.contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: videoFeedViewController.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        cell.contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: videoFeedViewController.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: "I am trying to implement Firework ios sdk to my project"  What is the thing that you so-call 'Firework ios sdk'?

Comment: i am refereeing to this https://github.com/loopsocial/firework_ios_sdk